# how to accept json string as parameter

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

i have wcf with method like

Void finalize(string jsonstring);

And i use request url like finalize/{json}

But if itried to call this with json it will give bad request  cause of charachters like : and so on

How to fix that

this is the code I use for the method

```
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "FinalBooking/{BookingJsonString}")]
        public int Finalize(string JsonString)
        {
            int result; // 1 success , 0 faill

            JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Routess routes =
                   (Routess)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(JsonString);
            using (XEntities context = new XEntities())
            {
                result = context.usp_Final(routes.TypeID, routes.regID, routes.CycleID, routes.DateTime,
                      routes.LocationID, routes.PatID, routes.PO, routes.BTID, routes.DID);



            }

            return result;

        }

    }
```

and example of the Data is simple JSON string like

```
{"DateTime":"03/09/2012 09:00","CycleID":6,"BTID":31,"DiseaseID":814,"LocID":36,"PatID":13,"PO":1,"TypeID":744,"rID":-1}
```

Best regards

Comment: are u sure `:` is the cause? `:` is legal in the request. can you post some code? and the json string you are passing?

Comment: also what binding are you using? http ?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your method, does it get into it? Does it pass the JSON string into your method, and the Json Serializer throws the error, or does WCF throw the error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you url-encoding your JSON string when you add it to your URL? If the URL was created from C# then you would use something like [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode) or in javascript, [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)

If you could show the URL as it is being sent, that would be helpful. Its not clear if the URL is the issue, or something in WCF.

---

*Edit:*

Looking at your posted code, I noticed your UriTemplate and your method parameter name don't match:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "FinalBooking/{BookingJsonString}")]
    public int Finalize(string JsonString)
```

`BookingJsonString` versus `JsonString`.

`UriTemplate` has 2 modes of binding: "Bind By Name", where the names are supposed to match, and "Bind By Position", where it ignores the names and just goes by parameter index.  I can't seem to find any info on which mode WCF WebInvoke uses, so you might want to try renaming your template or your parameter to match.

Comment: If the way you fixed it could help others, please post your fix as an answer, and then you can mark your own answer as the selected solution. That way if people come across this question later, it might help them out.